# Firefox Add-on SDK: Content Scripts use modules

Tags: firefox, module, firefox-addon-sdk

Are the content scripts loaded in the pages able to load other modules via `require()`, or would you have to emit a message to make the `main.js` get the module the emit a message back with the object desired?

(granted I know you can include multiple files into a single page)

Answer (score 0):

I have stick with the same problem. As the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Two_Types_of_Scripts#API_Access_for_Add-on_Code_and_Content_Scripts) says the `require` module is not available in the content scripts.

Then, i tried to overcome this by loading the `module` with

```
contentScriptFile:[data.url("../lib/my_module.js")]
```

But then, the `exports` keyword is undefined in content scripts. So, when you have a library like the following, it produces an error for exports keyword when you try to load it in the content script:

```
exports.test = function () { console.log("test"); }
```

So, you may have to duplicate your code, one for the addons code and one for the content script code.

The **sort answer** to the question in two sentenses is:

**You can not use modules in your content scripts**. You can duplicate your code or you can use(as the question says) messages.